# What is the remainder of $19^{1999}$ divided by 25?

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

How to solve this problem without using Euler's Theorem?n Any help is highly appreciated!

> What is the remainder of $19^{1999}$ divided by 25?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Euler's Theorem?

Comment: Euler's formula isn't that easy. Have t figure out $19^{19} $.  I found my answer much easier.

Comment: @fleablood Using Eulers, you get $19^{1999} \equiv 19^{-1} \equiv \frac{1}{19} \equiv \frac{-1}{6} \equiv \frac{24}{6} \equiv 4 \pmod{25}$... So it is very easy

Comment: Hmm, my calculator is being weird. Twice I 19^9 = 9 mod 25 which is clearly wrong... now it's giving me the correct answer.

Comment: Hmm, I figured 19x = 1 mod 25 is not very hard but tedious.  -6x = 1 mod 25. Is easier.  But honestly I've never liked solving those.  Still don't know why the op wanted to avoid euler.  Finding 19^10 =1 by hand and 19^9 =4 strikes me as near impossibly tedious.

Comment: @fleablood if $19^{20} \equiv 1$ then $19^{10} \equiv \pm 1$. And it has to be $+1$ since the last digit of $19^{10}$ is $1$. To get $19^9$, use my previous trick and you get $4$

Comment: The op for whatever bizarre reason said no euler.  Figuring out 19^10 and 19^9 **by hand WITHOUT euler** is tedious.  I still maintain that.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out what value of $n$ satisfies $19^n\equiv1\mod25$ just by trying all values of $n$ from $1$ to $25$. Once you get that value, which I will call $m$, you find $19^k\mod25$, where $k\equiv1999\mod m$. In this case, $m=10$, so you find $k\equiv1999\equiv9\mod10$. Your final solution is $19^{1999}\equiv19^9\equiv4\mod25$.

Answer (score 2):

$19^{1999} = (20-1)^{1999}=\sum (-1)^k a_k*20^{n-k} $

Note $20^2 =400 =16*25$.  So $25$ divides all but the last two terms.

So $19^{1999}$ will have the same remainder as $1999(-1)^{1998}20 + (-1)^{1999}=39980-1=39979=39975+4$ which has remainder $4$.

Comment: Of course if you get 20 x 1999 = 3996 you are screwed anyway..... sigh.